# How to style cells within columns of dataTables?

Tags: datatables

I have made a table (with child rows) using jQuery plug in dataTables. I'm having trouble finding out how to apply a style to an individual column of cells (`<td>`)

I've made an edit to this existing [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/eu4mbbta/1/) as you can see I've made the text larger in column 2, but I also want to make the text larger (plus other styling) in column 4 and 5.

I put a class in `line 114` in the CSS (this is the original css from dataTables) and this made the text bigger,

```
.sorting_1{
  font-size: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
}
```

it didn't work for the other columns (as I assumed `.sorting_2`, `.sorting_3` (etc) was the class to change it). When looking at the inspect panel you can see the `<td>` tag for the the changed cells all have the class of sorting_1, but the others don't and I'm not sure how to do that,

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row has the class of either `even` or `odd` so you could use `nth-of-type` to specify the `td` that you want to style and go from there.  You would have to style both the even and odd column so you would have to specify both like so:

```
.even td:nth-of-type(4), 
.odd td:nth-of-type(4){
  background:red;
}
.even td:nth-of-type(5), 
.odd td:nth-of-type(5){
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Or you could specify it by the role attribute and use `nth-of-type` like so:

```
tr[role=row] td:nth-of-type(4){
  background:red;
}
tr[role=row] td:nth-of-type(5){
  font-size:20px;
}
```